# Custom post type based on existing one

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Im using a theme that comes with a portfolio post type and portfolio categories taxonomy. My problem is that I want my site to have 3 portfolio sections, each with its own category list. 
Can I somehow "clone" the theme`s portfolio type and categories (and the admin section to edit them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need to create them (you can do so using plugins). Another approach is creating a different taxonomy to use as the section, or even a custom post field to filter, but in all of them you will need to edit your theme code.

Comment: I will try adding a new taxonomy for filtering.

Comment: Once the section taxonomy is added to the posts,  what is the preferred way to create menu item for a section? Can I pass an id parameter (per section) as menu attribute?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can use wp_query to change query to filter your custom taxonomies.

Comment: I want to add menu items for each section (portfolio type), how can I specify the section id as part of a menu item (so I could use this id to determine the post query to run when the menu item clicked). Is this clearer?

Comment: Never mind, I will use the page slug or a custom field to determine the section.